# How to send Raise_application_error message only to the front end?

Tags: oracle

How to send the `raise_application_error` message alone from the procedure?

```
ORA-20343: ERROR - FIRST_NAME IS MISSING and LAST_NAME IS MISSING
ORA-06512: at "quality.pkg_quality_check", line 113
ORA-06512: at line 28
```

I would like send only the first line of the error message. How to avoid the next two lines of the message?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since we don't know what your "front-end" is, hard to say. Just parse-out the first line of the message, no?

Comment: Have a look at [SQLERRM](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqlerrm_function.htm), this function returns only the top error message, not the full stack.

Answer (score 0):

I used to do this extensively in C#, and it was always easier to do as OldProgrammer recommends and just trap the OracleException and then parse out the bit of the message trace that was interesting, rather than get into messing about with stuff like DBMS_PIPE.PUT_MESSAGE to send lengthy error messages back to the client...

I don't have any of that old code around, but it was something like this:

```
try{
  //code here that calls oracle, could explode
}catch(System.Data.OracleException oex){
  string[] bits = oex.Message.Split('\n');
  if(bits.Length < 0 && bits[0].Contains(':'))
    MessageBox.Show(bits[0].Substring(bits[0].IndexOf(':') + 2));
  else
    MessageBox.Show(oex.Message);

}
```

I recall also that you could pass [a numerical argument to RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_raise_application_error.htm) and it would alter the `.Code` property of the OracleException, and that could be used to put nice messages in the front end:

```
switch(oex.Code){
  case 123456:
    MessageBox.Show("First name is too long");
    break;
  case 234567:
    MessageBox.Show("Last name is too long");
    break;
...
}
```

Remember that there may be slight differences in presentation/property naming etc if you use OracleClient data access library rather than Microsoft's one (I only ever used MS, and it have been at least 8 years since I wrote code in c#/oracle pair so apologies if some of this answer is a bit fuzzy)